# How can I reboot from windows to windows again? (remotely , windows-ubuntu multiboot)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, remote-access, reboot, multiboot

I use Windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04LTS on desktop
I want to use desktop from my laptop remotely.

My grub select ubuntu as a default os boot system.
And I know how to reboot the desktop from ubuntu to windows remotely
(sudo grub-reboot boot_number && sudo reboot)

But How can I reboot from windows to windows again?
In this situation, when I reboot from windows, ubuntu is selected as a default.
But sometimes, I want to reboot from windows to windows!

**In summary... 

1. I want to rebbot from windows to windows or ubuntu / from ubuntu to windows or ubuntu remotely. 

2. I know the way of rebbot other things. 

3. But I don't know how to reboot from windows to windows**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This isn't about programming specifically. Therefore your question is better asked @ http://unix.stackexchange.com/.
But I guess the only way is to access the filesystem of your Linux disk and edit the grub loader within windows: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11423/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-configuration-from-within-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to edit grub configuration from Ununtu first. The detailed steps are given [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18170/how-to-reboot-into-windows-from-ubuntu)

Comment: @SongKyungwoo if it helped you, can you please mark it as answer? It might help someone later.